# Pandas- how to split and merge columns with similar names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dirty dataframe which needs column cleaning. Basically, there are a LOT of columns which contain combination data which should not be and slight spelling differences! For example:

```
         1    1/2    2c     2 c     
row
1       B     nan    C       nan 
2       B     nan    C       nan
3       nan   Rb     nan     nan
4       c     nan    nan     C
```

to something like this:

```
         1    2c    
row
1       B     C       
2       B     C       
3       Rb    Rb   
4       c     C
```

Thus the issue is two fold, how do you merge columns which are split on fuzzy logic similarity and how do you split then merge on columns which have combo values?

The only way I know how to do this would be to create a new column which uses the .apply function to apply if statements, but given that the number of columns is in the 100s this would be painful. Any ideas for a less manual solution?

Comment: Fix the column names at the source please. Don't try to invent hacks to deal with it.

Comment: I dont have access to the source.

Comment: Open the CSV file and fix it? How many columns do you have?

Comment: As mentioned... 100s. I am asking if there is any other possible solution..... I dont like the situation I am in more than anyone else...

Comment: Yeah, there are next to infinite solutions, none of which may work for you. The problem is you've shown 4 columns here, not 400. There's no guarantee any solution given will extend to the actual data. This is too broad, but you may want to check out `difflib`, do pairwise comparisons and group columns. It's a start.

Comment: I have to agree with cs95 last point. Whatever logic you try to apply, needs to be true 100% of the time, or you won't be able to merge the columns successfully. Only you have access to all the columns, so you're going to have to figure out some underlying differentiating factor that equates columns x through y into a single column. We don't know what caused this, so we can't really propose a fix.

Comment: For example, how would you _know_ that `'1'=='1/2'`? To me, that looks like a very different proposition than `'2c' == '2 c'`

Comment: Thats fair, in this case I would argue just getting it down to be helpful. We can assume combos are on split("/") and ignore fuzzylogic

Comment: If columns are only differentiated by a split, then the answer is `df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('/').str[0], axis=1).first()` which is not what you're looking for! Never underestimate your problem, and never overestimate your solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### Try

```
d0 = df.filter(regex='/')      # Grab the columns with "/" in name
d1 = df.drop(d0, 1)            # Drop those columns

a = d0.to_numpy()              
m = d0.columns.str.count('/')  # Count the number of "/".

d2 = pd.DataFrame(
    a.repeat(m + 1, axis=1),   # Repeat the columns one more time than the # of "/"
    d0.index,
    np.concatenate(d0.columns.str.split('/')) 
)

d3 = pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1)  # Smash them back together

# Grab the first bit of the column name as long as they are digits
# Group by that and take the first non-null value
d3.groupby(np.ravel(d3.columns.str.extract('(\d+)')), axis=1).first()

    1   2
1   B   C
2   B   C
3  Rb  Rb
4   c   C
```